# Irreducibilty (reducibility) of a family of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k\geq 3$ and $p\geq 1$ be integers. Set $f_{k,p}(x):=x^k-px^{k-1}-(p+1)x-1$. I need to prove for which parameters $k$ and $p$, this polynomial is irreducible (over $\mathbb{Z}$). For instance, $f_{5,1}(x)$ is the only example that I find to be reducible, since it is divisible by $x^2-x-1$.

Anyone could give some suggestion or idea? Some useful criterion (I was not able to use Eisenstein and Perron method also does not work).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $p$ supposed to be a prime? If so, then $f_{k,p}$ reduces to an Artin-Schreier polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Oiler But Artin-Schreirer polynomial requires k=p to be prime too, right?

Comment: Correct. My mistake I forgot about the second parameter.